# style a disc inside of the span inside of the p element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very strange requirement, where in I have to display a list-style disc inside of a  which resides inside a p tag. Since Even though span is an inline level element, think because of the nature of p tag, the list renders in the second line. I want to have the text in both span and p to render in a single line. Here is a screenshot for your reference

[image]

As you can see after the (Central Time Zone) text, I want the disc and the text Monday-Friday render in the same line. I am not able to find how to figure this. Thanks a lot for help in advance. Here is what I have tried so far.

```css
.body-text-info {
  font-family: Nexa W01 XBold !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #000 !important;
}

.center-text-details {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue LT Pro Roman !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #77777A !important;
}

.bullet-disc {
  list-style: disc outside none !important;
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<section id="extra-info">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="center-text-details">8:00am - 5:00pm (Central Time Zone) <span class="bullet-disc"> Monday - Friday </span></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why don't you change your `list-style` to display `inside` rather than `outside`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Or** use `pseudo-element` if you don't want use `ul li` according to `@Shital Marakana` answer.

```
.bullet-disc::before {
    content: "●";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.body-text-info {
  font-family: Nexa W01 XBold !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #000 !important;
}

.center-text-details {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue LT Pro Roman !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #77777A !important;
}

.bullet-disc {
    display: block;
}

.bullet-disc::before {
    content: "●";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="extra-info">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="center-text-details">8:00am - 5:00pm (Central Time Zone) <span class="bullet-disc"> Monday - Friday </span></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-indent` to the `bullet-disc class`, and then add the bullet style using the `:before` css tag

```css
.body-text-info {
  font-family: Nexa W01 XBold !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #000 !important;
}

.center-text-details {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue LT Pro Roman !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #77777A !important;
}

.bullet-disc {
  display: block;
  text-indent: 35px;
  position: relative;
}
.bullet-disc:before{
  content: '•';
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="extra-info">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="center-text-details">8:00am - 5:00pm (Central Time Zone) <span class="bullet-disc"> Monday - Friday </span></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can display disc style by using ul li.**

```css
.body-text-info {
  font-family: Nexa W01 XBold !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #000 !important;
}

.center-text-details {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue LT Pro Roman !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  color: #77777A !important;
}

.center-text-details ul li {
  list-style: disc outside none !important;
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<section id="extra-info">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="center-text-details">8:00am - 5:00pm (Central Time Zone) <ul><li>Monday - Friday</li></ul></p>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```